# Java Generics Type losts constant type when a type parameter is declared in class

Tags: java, generics

I'm using Oracle JDK 7u79. I don't know why the code below produces compilation error:

```
package generics;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

class SomeClass {
    public Collection<String> getStringCollection() {
        return Collections.singleton("hello");
    }
}

class SomeTypedClass<T> {
    public Collection<String> getStringCollection() {
        return Collections.singleton("hello");
    }
}

public class SomeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int length1 = new SomeClass()     .getStringCollection().iterator().next().length();
        final int length2 = new SomeTypedClass().getStringCollection().iterator().next().length(); // compilation error
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Error:(21, 89) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method length()
  location: class java.lang.Object
```

I've specified constant generics type `Collection<String>` as method parameter for `getStringCollection()` so I think both `SomeClass` and `SomeTypedClass` should be compiled without error.

Why this happen? And what is the proper solution which is getting constantly typed `Collection` without casting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, since your `SomeTypedClass<T>` expects a type `T` passed in, even though it's not using the type, you'll need to do this in `SomeTest`:

```
public class SomeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int length1 = new SomeClass()     .getStringCollection().iterator().next().length();
        final int length2 = new SomeTypedClass<String>().getStringCollection().iterator().next().length(); // no more compilation error
    }
}
```

I used a `String`, but you could use `Object` if you wanted to since `T` isn't actually being used.

It may be worth considering doing something more like this with your `SomeTypedClass` class, depending on what your real-world scenario is:

```
class SomeTypedClass<T> {
    public Collection<T> getTypedCollection(T object) {
        return Collections.singleton(object);
    }
}
```

You could then do:

```
final int length2 = new SomeTypedClass<String>().getTypedCollection("hello").iterator().next().length();
```

If you're only interested in classes that derive from `String`, you could also do something like this:

```
class SomeTypedClass<T extends String> {
    public Collection<T> getStringCollection(T object) {
        return Collections.singleton(object);
    }
}
```

You could then do:

```
final int length2 = new SomeTypedClass<String>().getStringCollection("hello").iterator().next().length();
```

Comment: Nice, But it looks bit awkward because `<Object>` has completely no meaning. I don't want to put it everywhere...

Comment: Thanks for the edit, It makes sense if I want to use `<T>` as something like `Collection<T> getTypedCollection()` but unfortunately I don't want any variable type for that method. Instead, I want a constant generics type for that method in my real-world scenario. I'll use `<T>` for other methods but not for that particular one.